# How do i handle click events on markers that are on a GeoJsonLayer on google map android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I have found plenty of documentation on how to style it but none regarding how to listen to and handle events.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have already got solution to your problem, but one way to workaround it is use  `setOnMapLongClickListener` in place of `setOnMapClickListener`. I hope this help you.

Comment: I solved it. But yours will be helpful for others. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the below given Link:- official Events doc for maps

[REFERENCE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events)